# How to append parameters to every external url with angular

Tags: angular

Just looking for some ideas on what people think about using angular to add a parameter to every external url, or a url that contains a specific domain.

Use https://cdn.mydomain.com/ as an example. If I were to use jquery, on document ready I could do something like:

```
$(‘a[href*=https://cdn.mydomain.com/]’).attr(‘href’,function(i,href){
    return href + ‘?key=dhshowbdh’;
});
```

Just wondering how people would accomplish this in angular 8, without using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use HttpInterceptor in Angular.

Comment: Actually we already use one to put a security key on post requests so I quite like this solution

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, except from typescript strong typing, there's no special "angular way" of doing it but regular DOM API functions. I assume that every single part of your links is out of your control (e.g. you just receive it from somewhere and show them on the page). You can do:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const $anchors: NodeListOf<HTMLAnchorElement> = document.querySelectorAll(
    'a[href*="https://cdn.mydomain.com/"]'
  );
  $anchors.forEach(($anchor: HTMLAnchorElement) => {
    $anchor.href += '?key=dhshowbdh';
  });
}
```